Are $X_i \varepsilon_i$ iid?
Take:

$X_i , \ i = 1, ... , n $  iid.

$\varepsilon_i , \ i = 1, ... ,n$ also iid.

$X_i  \not \perp \varepsilon_j$ (they are not necessarily independent)


Are $X_i \varepsilon_i$ iid ?

To get a feel for this, and a method to construct counterexamples, suppose $X_i$ has zero chance of being zero and define $\varepsilon_i=1/X_i.$

I guess by $X_i \not \perp \epsilon_j$ you mean that the sample covariance is 0?

@whuber That example would make each $X_i\epsilon_i=1$ with probability $1$, and they would then be iid compared with each other.

@Henry I never claimed otherwise.  Think a little about how you could turn this into a counterexample.

Are the $(X_i,\epsilon_i)$ iid?
